# Calculating error of estimation of signal from noisy data (Explanation of result)

Tags: signal, signal-processing

Given random varaible X with distribution $$ \begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)=\alpha\\
\mathbb{P}\left(X=-1\right)=1-\alpha
\end{cases} $$

Where \$ \alpha \$ is a given parameter(\$X\$ is a binary signal), and noise \$Z\$ with normal distribution \$ Z\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^{2}\right) \$, we define the random varaible $$ Y=X+Z $$

We Assume \$ X,Z \$ are independent random variables.

Now, in order to estimate \$ X \$ by the samples \$ Y \$, we decide that if \$ Y \geq \gamma \$ then \$ X=1 \$, and if \$ Y< \gamma \$ then \$ X=-1 \$, where \$ \gamma \$ is some value.

Now, the probability of a mistake is given by:

$$ \mathbb{P}_{\text{error}}\left(\gamma\right)=\left(1-\alpha\right)-\left(1-\alpha\right)F_{Z}\left(\gamma+1\right)+\alpha F_{Z}\left(\gamma-1\right) $$

And I was supposed to find \$ \gamma \$ such that the error would be minimal. I did the calculations and proved that this probability accepts its minimal value for $$ \gamma=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\right) $$

Now I'm asked to explain why this result makes sense. Putting the calculations aside, Im not sure why would this particular \$\gamma \$ lead to minimal error. I'd really appreciate an idea or explanation.

**Other results I have calculated and may be important for the explanation**

The density of \$ Y \$ : $$ f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{\left(y-1\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}+\left(1-\alpha\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{\left(y+1\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}} $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not exclusively an EE question but, a question about math that seeks to find an idea or explanation (likely an opinion).

Comment: @Andyaka In my opinion it has nothing to do with math, Im looking for physical explanation for my math calculations

Answer (score 0):

Just a start:
If α = 0.50 (1 or -1 are equally likely), then one would expect the value of the decision variable, γ, to be at the midpoint between the 2 values of X which is 0. Indeed, when α = .5, your equation gives the value of γ as 0.
You then should consider what should happen as α approaches 1 and as α approaches 0.